# return value of chrome.webRequest based chrome.storage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrequest

Save and restore options!

I'm trying to block some sites through WebRequest, but when the ckeckbox this false even still blocking the site, anyone can help, this is the code that I have

Options.js

```
function save_options(){
  var blockurl_1 = document.getElementById("blockurl_1").checked;
  var blockurl_2 = document.getElementById("blockurl_2").checked;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    blockurl_1: blockurl_1,
    blockurl_2: blockurl_2
  }, function() {
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Block';
  });
}

function restore_options() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    blockurl_1: false,
    blockurl_2: false
  }, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('blockurl_1').checked = items.blockurl_1;
    document.getElementById('blockurl_2').checked = items.blockurl_2;
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
var checkcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("save")[0];
    checkcontent.addEventListener("click",save_options);
```

I need to do this myself, but with chrome.storage

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    return {
        cancel: ( localStorage["block_chat_seen"] == 'true' ) ? true : false
    }
}, { urls: ['*://*.facebook.com/'] }, ['blocking'])
```

...

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(items) {

            if (items.blockurl_1) {
                chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) { 
                    var state = (blockurl_1 === true) ? 'true' : 'false';
                    return { cancel: state }; }, {
                        urls: ["*://www.google.com.co/*"]
                    },
                ["blocking"]);
            }

            if (items.blockurl_2) {
                chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) { 
                    var state = (blockurl_2 === true) ? 'true' : 'false';
                    return { cancel: state }; }, {
                        urls: ["*://www.youtube.com.co/*"]
                    },
                ["blocking"]);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are **adding** listeners each time.

You need to clear existing ones before adding a new one.

Comment: You could explain with an example, I am a newbie with javascript

Comment: I'll try when I'm not on mobile